# how can I find E(XY) using the moment generating function?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Let $X,Y$ a random variable with density $f(x,y)=\frac{2}{5}(2x+3y),\quad 0<x<1, 0<y<1$.

Find the joint moment generating function.

I find that the answer is:

$$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)={4\over5}(\frac{e^{t_1}}{t_1}-\frac{e^{t_1}-1}{t_1^2})(\frac{e^{t_2}-1}{t_2})+{6\over5}(\frac{e^{t_2}}{t_2}-\frac{e^{t_2}-1}{t_2^2})(\frac{e^{t_1}-1}{t_1})$$

I want to know if it is correct

Comment: Do you mean the joint density for $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: ... and the joint MGF?

Comment: I need the joint MGF

Comment: Your calculation is correct. However, it usually requires that Mxy exists at the neighborhood of zero for t1 and t2. So in this case the Mxy would not help to calculate EXY since it does not exist at point zero.

Comment: I edited the first sentence, please see if you agree

Comment: then, there is no way to calculate the E(XY) with the joint MGF?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it.

$$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)=E[e^{t_1 X + t_2Y }]=\int \int e^{t_1 x}e^{t_2 y } \frac{2}{5}(2x+3y) dx dy$$

It's too hot here in the south, I'll use Maxima:

```
f(x,y):=(2*x+3*y)*(2/5);

ratsimp(
 (4/5)*(%e^t1/t1-(%e^t1-1)/t1^2)*((%e^t2-1)/t2)  + 
 (6/5)*(%e^t2/t2-(%e^t2-1)/t2^2)*((%e^t1-1)/t1)  -
 integrate(integrate(f(x,y) *exp(t1*x)*exp(t2*y), x, 0, 1),y,0,1)
);

0
```

So it's ok.

The title also asks about computing $E(XY)$ from the $M_{XY}$

You can do that by applying $$\frac{\partial^2 M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)}{\partial t_1 \partial t_2} \biggr\rvert_{t_1=0,t_2=0}=E(XY)$$

but 1) you must be sure that you are allowed to do that (the MGF is well behaved around zero) 2) you might consider it too cumbersome

In this case, it might appear that 1) does not apply - the MGF seems to blow up at zero, but that's not so, there is an indeterminancy that we can resolve by Taylor expansion. Because $e^x=1+x+x^2/2 +x^3/6+O(x^4)$ we have:

$$\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+O(x^2)$$

and

$$\frac{e^{x}}{x}-\frac{e^{x}-1}{x^2}=\frac{x+x^2+x^3/2- (x+x^2/2+x^3/6) + O(x^4)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}x+O(x^2)$$

Then, disregarding $O(x^2)$ terms:

$$ M_{XY}(t_1,t_2) =
\frac{4}{5}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}t_1)(1+\frac{1}{2}t_2)+
\frac{6}{5}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}t_2)(1+\frac{1}{2}t_1) + O(t_1^2)O(t_2^2)
$$

(to check: $M_{XY}(0,0)=1$)

Can you follow on from here? I get $E(XY)=1/3$

(Of course, it would have been easier to compute $E(XY)$ directly by integration, but I guess that's not the point).

Comment: Do you know if this expresion for joint MGF can be useful to  calculate the E(XY)?

Comment: That's the problem of putting your question on the title and not on the body :-) I missed that, I'll go with it

Comment: Thanks for your help and answer, using the integrals I find that E(XY)=1/3 , and I wanted to verify this result with the MGF but I didn´t know that it would be toilful.

Comment: Very interesting approach. Since original mgf does not exist around (0,0) point, I only think to use direct integral EXY. But as for the $O(x^4)$ , the remainder notation, I am still in doubt since the derivative does not exist. This means there could be a problem of writing in this form. thx

Comment: "Since original mgf does not exist around (0,0) point" It actually exists, it's just an indetermination. The same with the derivatives. The MGF is well behaved.